# Find length/count of entity with condition in twig

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I am trying to figure out how to show `many` relationship entries based on a field of the entry.

So, a `category` has many `hardware` entries, and a `hardware` entry has a field `client`.

I would now like to display the `category` in my twig template IF the `category` is not empty (so has hardware entries) AND the count of hardware entries WITH a specific client(id) is > 0.

So sth like this (this doe not work):

```
{% if type.hardware.contains(client)|length > 0 %}
    {# DO whatever #}
{% endif %}
```

`client` is a `ManyToOne` connection from `hardware`.

Is there a way to do that in Twig or do I have to work around it in my php controller?

//EDIT

Ok, I understand it is better to put the logic in my controller, I came up with this, but this does not show the type if there is no hardware attached (it should)

```
$types = $qb->select(array('t','h'))
        ->from('AppBundle:Type', 't')
        ->join('t.hardware', 'h')
        ->where('h.client = :client')
        ->setParameter('client', $client)
        ->orderBy('t.sortOrder', 'ASC')
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
```

So if a type has hardware it will show, otherwise it will not. I tried to add

`->orWhere($qb->expr()->isNull('t.hardware'))` but that throws a mysql error:

> line 0, col 100 near 'hardware IS NULL': Error: Invalid PathExpression.

Comment: Better do do this in query builder or DQL

Comment: "work around it in my php controller?". Logic should NEVER go in a view file. Do the logic in your PHP, and send the OUTPUT (or array) to the view. The view should ONLY contain echoes, or loops and echoes.

Comment: edited the code according to your suggestion

Answer (score 2):

How about these, they all come out of a working project, it depends on how you retreive your data:

```
{% if type.hardware.contains(client) %}
// or
{% if type.hardware.contains(client) not empty %}
// or
{% if type.hardware.contains(client)|length != 0 %}
```